# If UIWebview url is equal to

Tags: ios, uiwebview, storyboard

I got a UIWebView called "homeview". Everytime someone is browsing the UIWebview I want to check if the page url is "http://www.website.com/cart" and then change the tab controller to the second tab.

So I did it like this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)homeview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
if ([URLString isEqualToString:@"http://www.website.com/cart"]) {
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
}
return YES;
}
```

But with no luck... So I tried to get an alert when page is equal to the url with:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)homeview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
if ([URLString isEqualToString:@"http://www.website.com/cart"]) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Alert Title here"
                                                   message: @"Alert Message here"
                                                  delegate: self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                         otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];


    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
return YES;
}
```

But that didn't the trick as well...

The above code is placed in my FirstViewController.m and this is my FirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;
IBOutlet UIWebView *homeview;
NSTimer *timer;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *homepage;

@end
```

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: So, have you seen the UIAlertView? Put NSLog("Load url %@", urlString); before "if" clause

Comment: Have you set the webView's delegate using: [homepage setDelegate:self] (or using the Interface Builder)?

Comment: @gWiz, no.. I added this to the viewdidload:

[_homepage setDelegate:self];

But it's giving me a warning:  Sending 'FirstViewController *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UIWebViewDelegate>'

Comment: You should change this: `@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController` to this: `@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>` to get rid of the warning and possibly fix your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this:**

Use **Compare:**to compare two strings.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)homeview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
if ([URLString Compare:@"http://www.website.com/cart"]==NSOrderedSame) {
    self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it's still not working.. Here is an example;

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)homeview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if([urlString compare: @"http://www.sportdirect.com/order/cart" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, 37)] == NSOrderedSame) {
        
// alert

Comment: Can you sense the difference between the url you are comparing and the url you are getting.Print and check.May be some issue down there.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect part of the problem is that you are looking for an *exact* match to the URL "`http://www.website.com/cart`" while the URL that's really being loaded by your web view is something like "`http://www.website.com/cart?userid=123456&order=abcdefg&giftidea=something+expensive`".

Your idea seems like a decent approach to me at first glance, but try changing this line:

```
if ([URLString isEqualToString:@"http://www.website.com/cart"]) {
```

to this:

```
if([URLString compare: @"http://www.website.com/cart" options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, 27)] == NSOrderedSame)
```

and see if you have a happier result.

Also, for more readable code, Apple suggests that Objective-C variables and objects all start with lower case letters.  So instead of "`URLString`", use "`urlString`" or something even more descriptive, like "`urlAsString`" or "`urlStringFromWebView`".

Answer (score 0):

If url loaded by UIWebView is not exactly equal to yours then you can check that location of your string isn't empty. F.e.:

```
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString]
            rangeOfString:@"http://www.website.com/cart"].location != NSNotFound) { ... }
```

Or you can check the line @"www.website.com/cart" to take into account https protocol