# How to handle Call Back URL when opening link using a webView

Tags: ios, callback, uiwebview, fitbit, garmin

I have a situation here. We are trying to connect **Garmin** tracker in our app. Now It does not support authentication like **Fitbit** etc. So we planned to handle it on server Side. Now My Server is giving  me a link which I should open in a `UIWebView` or in Safari. User will enter their UserName and Password of Garmin account and when successful it will be send  a link of our server. Now server wants to notify me weather the user is successfully logged in or not.

How Can I close the webView or Safari Browser in this case ? Can I provide a callBack URL to my server and server can redirect me to the app ?

Please guide me and instead of downVoting just guide me to a right direction.

Comment: why you are not doing user authentication through web services? why use web view for it?

Comment: what do you mean by webService ? User need to login to their account on the mobile. Like when we connect facebook. We authenticate the user and then move on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check callurl as below :

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)homeview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSString *URLString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    if ([URLString Compare:@"callback url"]==NSOrderedSame) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
    }
    return YES;
    }
```

from link : [If UIWebview url is equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846469/if-uiwebview-url-is-equal-to?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Actually What i tried is Opend the URL in safari and after loggin in my server redirected me to my App. But safari promted that do you want to open "MyApplication" ? now user say yes an I cam back to my applicatoion. But How Can I detect that is the user is logged in ?

Comment: you need to register URL scheme in your app and post while successful login in safari . and handle url application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: in appdelgate

Comment: check url for register url scheme : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201724/how-to-register-a-custom-app-opening-url-scheme-with-xcode-4